# how to set button to be visible only after i made changes in 2 dropdownlists in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

in aspx file I have

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" >
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="load_data" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources : load_data %>"  
    onclick="load_data_class_Click" Visible="False"/>
```

Now I want to set button to be visible only after i made changes in 2 dropdownlists in javascript

how to do this?

Comment: you could add classes, when the drop down value is changed, and at every change you look if the other dropdown has the class and then set visible true for your button !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you can't use Visible="false", you need to use CSS and set visibility: hidden;, or display:none.

Once you've done that, you can do the following ->

Get the ID's of the lists:

```
//id #1
var ddl1 = document.getElementById("DropDownList1");

//id #2
var ddl2 = document.getElementById("DropDownList2");
```

Now, we need to create an onChange function to grab the values, and test if they're empty, if not, then we'll show the button.

```
function showButton(){
  //out of <option value="3"> This is 3rd </option> you get:
  var selected1text = ddl1.option[ddl.selectedIndex].text; // returns: This is 3rd
  var selected1value = ddl1.option[ddl.selectedIndex].val; // returns: 3

  //out of <option value="75"> This is 75th </option> you get:
  var selected2text = ddl2.option[dd2.selectedIndex].text; // returns: This is 75th
  var selected2value = ddl2.option[dd2.selectedIndex].val; // returns: 75

  if(
    selected1text != "" &&
    selected1value != "" &&
    selected2text != "" &&
    selected2value != ""
  ){
    //Our select lists all have values. We can show our button now.

    //if you use visibility:hidden;
    document.getElementById('load_data').style.visibility='visible';

    //if you use display:none;
    document.getElementById('load_data').style.display='block';
  }else{
    //don't do anything.
  }
}
```

Then, in your dropdown list, you can add the onChange=showButton();

Should work.

Answer (score 3):

Markup will not be generated for ASP.NET controls whose `Visible` property is set to `False`. You need to apply CSS (display:none or visibility) via JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

You can take one `hidden` element with value `0` and whenever someone change the dropdown, increment the value of this hidden element and when it reaches equal to 2 then show the button.

Basically you need to call a function on change event of both drop-down which will do the above thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
   I solved the problem with jquery

  $(document).ready(function () {


             $('#load_data').live('click', function () {

                 var result;
                 if (($('#DropDownList1 option:selected').val() != '') &&
                     ($('#DropDownList2 option:selected').val() != '') &&
                      ($('#DropDownList3 option:selected').val() != '')) {
                     //result = true;
                     alert("true");
                     result = true;
                 } else {
                     //  result= false;
                     alert("false");
                     result = false;
                 }
                 return result;
             });
         });
```